# Scrolling images from right to left

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview, right-to-left

I'm trying to scroll many images from right to left. I found many tutorials on how to do that, but the thing is that I want many small images to appear at the same time in the UIScrollView as in the below image.

[image: UIScrollView with many images inside it]

Thanks!

Comment: scroll views can scroll left and right... you just set the content size [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)] you can put as many images as you wait and tell the width to be what ever you want and it will scroll accordingly make sure to not enable paging... that's probably the odd thing you did in the tutorials

Comment: I'm doing exactly like what you're saying: paging is not enabled and ofc scrolling is enabled but it's still not working.

Comment: I'm using storyboard, does it affect the scrolling?

Comment: I had to disable auto layout in the File Inspector for it to work